# Git index and working-tree EOL values do not match those set in .gitattributes

Tags: git, utf-8, git-bash, egit

I am on Windows, using `git` through the `git bash` CLI. I have a `.java` file using `UTF-8` encoding which I imported to `git` from an old `svn` server. My coworkers, also on Windows but using the `git` client from the Eclipse IDE, constantly complain of having whitespace changes on checkout (i.e. without any manual modification) with this particular file. I **believe** that the issue has to do with `git` treating the files as binary, but I am not certain of that. The output of `ls-files --eol` is:

```
$ git ls-files --eol -- src/Props.java 
i/-text w/-text attr/text=auto eol=crlf src/Props.java
```

The above seems to indicate that `git` believes the stored version of the file to be binary (the `i/-text w/-text` bit) but also recognizes the attribute settings in the repository (the `attr/text=auto eol=crlf` bit). How is this possible? Is there a way to fix it so that what is stored in the index/working tree is `crlf`? Am I even looking in the right place to resolve this issue?

Comment: `text=auto` tells Git to *guess*. The output you're seeing says that Git did guess, and its guess was "these are binary files". The guessing isn't configurable, but you can force Git to believe that a file is text (or isn't text) with `text` or `-text` in `.gitattributes`. However, if Git is guessing that the file is binary, it's probably not text (e.g., it might be stored as UTF16, which to Git isn't text and which Git may damage if you make it treat it as text and do EOL conversions).

Comment: It can be hard to tell if a file has been converted from UTF-8 to UTF-16-LE by some errant Windows software, because other software that inspects the file will see that it's UTF-16-LE, *convert* it to UTF-8, and then inspect it and proudly announce that the file is now UTF-8. When your tools lie to you—and so many modern ones do—things get difficult.

Comment: OK, so let's say that I **REALLY** wanted to tell `git` to treat this file as `text` with `crlf` line endings. I would need some way to know for sure what the encoding was and then some way of replacing those characters which trick `git` into believing it's a binary, right?  Thoughts on how to do those two things? I have full control of this file and it does not NEED to be UTF-16 (or any other special encoding) so modifying the file manually is not an issue. (FWIW, `Notepad++` believes it's UTF-8 and `file -i Props.java` gives `text/x-java; charset=us-ascii`)

Comment: If the file really is text, it's odd that Git would guess wrong, but simply changing `text=auto` to `text` in your `.gitattributes` will tell Git that files are text. (What to change or add depends on what's already in the `.gitattributes` file: if you have `* text=auto` you might add `*.java text` below that to override just for the `.java` files, for instance. Add `eol=crlf` to make Git turn \n to \r\n on the way out of the repository to the working tree, and to turn \r\n to \n only on the way from the working tree into the repository, if that's what you want.)

Comment: Note that the different `eol=` settings direct Git as to whether to do \n => \r\n on the way out, and whether to do \r\n => \n on the way in. The settings are: do both, or do just the input-to-repository side (\r\n => \n) conversion. These are the only conversion options available: there's no \n to \r\n on the way in to the repository option, for instance. `-text` (or `binary`) means *hands off*, `text` means *hands on*, and `eol=` sets the conversion(s).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `text=auto`, that asks Git to look at the file, and if it finds any NUL bytes within a certain number of bytes from the beginning of the file, it considers the file binary, and otherwise it considers the file to be text.  Usually this approach works well, but sometimes it doesn't.

One of the places it doesn't is if you're using UTF-16.  This is very popular on Windows and is still used in some programming languages, but is generally considered obsolete everywhere else in favor of UTF-8.  UTF-16 with characters from the ASCII range (i.e., most English text and programming languages) will contain NUL bytes, which will make Git think the text is binary.  Note that to Git, anything where the LF and CR characters are represented by something other than their values in US-ASCII (like the two-byte sequences in UTF-16) is binary and forcing text conversions there will break things.

If these files are really in some ASCII-compatible encoding (e.g., UTF-8) and you want to force Git to detect these files as text, you can modify your `.gitattributes` file as such:

```
*.java text
```

If you also want the EOL to be CRLF, then do this:

```
*.java text eol=crlf
```

Any time you set Git to perform text conversion, it will store LF endings in the repository.  This is what you want regardless of the endings in the working tree, because it makes tools like `git diff` work better without screaming about your trailing whitespace (the CR).  Setting `eol=crlf` just forces this to be CRLF in the working tree, which is going to be what you need for most programs to work.

Note that in general, the recommendation is to just let folks use the line endings they prefer and only set line endings when they're needed for functionality, like LF for shell scripts and CRLF for batch scripts, where the alternative is that it just doesn't work.  However, there are some environments where tooling causes problems, so you may wish to set configuration in those environments as well.